# ¿Cómo puedo usar la clase `vector` para generar una matriz de 3*3?

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo usar la clase `vector` para generar una matriz de 3*3?

Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num=0,j,i;
    vector<int> numero[3][3]; //tengo que utilizar el contenedor vector y que sea una matriz
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cin>>numero[i][j];//pero no puedo hacer que me de a la hora de pedir un dato y probe de diferentes maneras
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout<<numero[i,j];
        }
                cout<<" "<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta carece de la informacion necesaria para que alguno de nosotros pueda ayudarte. Por favor consulta la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorarla.

Comment: Bienvenido StackOverflow en Español. Por consenso en la comunidad, las preguntas sobre *ejercicios* **deben** incluir el código realizado hasta el momento. No tienes mas que [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/60784/edit) tu pregunta para mostrárnoslo.

Comment: Edwin Casco, aquí no se vienen a pedir tareas de programación, tienes que trabajar por ti mismo y traer al sitio dudas puntuales

Comment: ya escribi el codigo ayudame porfavor

Comment: Estas declarando un vector unidimensional, debes indicar que cada posición contiene un vector dentro `vector<vector<int>> matriz(filas, std::vector<int>(columnas));`

Comment: gracias por ayudarme si me funciono

Comment: @GerardoLopezDueñas, considera generar una respuesta, al parecer al usuario le sirvió lo que comentas. Voto para abrir esta pregunta - y así puedas responder.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo puedo usar la clase `vector` para generar una matriz de 3*3?

¡Ya lo has hecho!

```
vector<int> numero[3][3];
```

El código anterior crea una matriz de 3 filas y 3 columnas cuyos elementos son vectores de enteros.

---

Pero a la vista del resto de código que publicas, lo que querías es una matriz de 3 filas y 3 columnas cuyos elementos fueran enteros, así que lo que esperas es esto:

```
int numero[3][3];
```

Que es totalmente compatible con tu código de lectura de datos:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        cin>>numero[i][j]; // Ningun fallo al leer! :)
    }
}
```

> Tengo que utilizar el contenedor vector y que sea una matriz.

Algo estoy entendiendo mal, porque una matriz de `vector` no es lo que necesitas como ya hemos podido ver antes. **Ninguna de las soluciones siguientes usa una matriz**:

Con un arreglo (matriz de una dimensión) de `vector` podrías aproximarte a la idea de matriz:

```
vector<int> numero[3] { {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} };
```

El código anterior crea un arreglo (matriz de 1 dimensión) de tres `vector` y cada uno de ellos tiene 3 elementos, así que tu código de lectura de datos funciona de la misma manera; es importante dar datos a cada `vector` pues de lo contrario el programa fallaría en tiempo de ejecución; pero puedes cambiar la lógica de lectura para que no falle:

```
vector<int> numero[3]; // Sin datos iniciales!!

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        int valor;
        cin>>valor;
        numero[i].push_back(valor);
    }
}
```

Finalmente existe la opción de hacer un `vector` de `vector` (como sugiere [Gerardo Lopez Dueñas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60784/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-usar-la-clase-vector-para-generar-una-matriz-de-33#comment109643_60784)):

```
vector<vector<int>> numero { {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} };
```

Pero si quieres conservar la misma lógica de lectura de datos deberás darle datos iniciales (o fallará en tiempo de ejecución); o si prefieres no darle datos iniciales puedes usar la función `push_back` como hemos visto hace unas líneas.